# Change password in B2C

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to check user has given his correct password in B2C  ? I need to develop a functionality in my blazor/.net 5 app to enable users to change their password in B2C. Before they set new password , old password given by the user needs to be verified. Could any one provide some directions in this regards?

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a [password reset flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow) in Azure AD B2C.

When creating *Sign up and sign in (Recommended)* flow, select **Self-service password reset** under Password configuration.

**Or** create a password reset user flow under User flows in the portal.

---

If you want to enable users to change their password **without** having to prove their identity through **email verification**, you could consider configuring a [password change flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I wanted to verify users current password before updating it with new password which is not possible with password reset flow

Comment: The step2 of password change flow is to verify the Old password. *"The user verifies the Old password, and then creates and confirms the New password."* https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOJpO.png

Comment: Is there a direct way to implement this functionality rather than using custom policy for password change ?  Like using graph client ? 

If I can validate the user Id and password before allowing him to update with new password, that will fulfil my requirement.

Comment: This [Azure AD graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) may suitable for you: `POST https://graph.windows.net/me/changePassword?api-version  {
  "currentPassword": "Test1234!",
  "newPassword": "Test5678!"
}`